# MS Access: read-only linked tables from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there any way to link tables from SQL Server to Access as read-only?

There's too much data to do an import.

Comment: Another, hackish, way is to remove the primary key of the linked table through SQL: `DROP INDEX PrimaryKey ON myTable`. It makes the table read-only too, but the side effect of not having the PK is usually not desirable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While providing the credentials to choose the tables from your SQL database, you can configure this SQL user to have read only permissions.

- Add tables to Access database (trough Linked tables)
- Set SQL user (or Windows User, or Role) to "datareader" only. (in SQL Management Studio)

Comment: There is a lot to be said for creating roles and adding users https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms187936.aspx

Comment: I just tried it this way, by adding a new SQL login with only the datareader role only. However, if I make any changes to the Access DB, they are also made in the SQL DB.