# Read only link between MS Access and a remote Informix db

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, informix

I'm trying to create a link between MS Access and a remote Informix db.
The Access db will be used for generating reports/views etc with the data from the linked Informix db.

I have setup a DSN for the Informix DB and can connect to it.
Using the MS Access 2016 GUI I can select to create a link via the external data tab. However, I need to make sure that this is a read only link. It is imperative that any changes made (either on purpose or accident) in the linked access db do not filter back.

One option I have considered was contacting the Informix DBA to make sure my account is read only. Unfortunately, this is not possible, so I wonder if there is some other approach I can take?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access: read-only linked tables from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33694068/2144390)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do to create a read-only connection.

The most secure way, in general, is to create a user that only has read access, and use that user for your DSN (also fixes the issue that DSN information is publicly available in Access and might be reused.

Another way is to set `SQL_ACCESS_MODE` to `1` (=`SQL_MODE_READ_ONLY`) in your DSN file, which creates a read-only connection on supported databases. However, a tech-savvy user can just change that value, so this doesn't add the security the first way provides.

Comment: Note that [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525699(v=vs.90).aspx) says that `SQL_ACCESS_MODE` is "An indicator for the ODBC driver", i.e., a hint, and that "The behavior of the driver and data source when asked to process SQL statements that are not read-only during a read-only connection is implementation-defined." FWIW, I just tested both `SQL_ACCESS_MODE=1` and `ApplicationIntent=READONLY` with a linked table using ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server and neither one prevented me from updating the SQL Server table via my linked table in Access.

Comment: previous comment TL;DR: `SQL_ACCESS_MODE` does not necessarily *enforce* a read-only connection.

Answer (score 1):

Informix ODBC doesn't support SQL_ACCESS_MODE and as far as I know, there is no option that would make a 'read-only' connection.

You can ask our DBA to create a view on the table and restrict access on just that view (e.g. only have the 'SELECT' permission on it). Then use that view as the source for your linked table.

A second option would be to not have a linked table, just import the data from the source.

Comment: It does support `SQL_ACCESS_MODE` according to [this document](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/informixU2/ifmxcli.pdf) in the CLI, so ODBC connections should support it too (well, as far as I understand, the documentation is marginal at best).

Comment: @J_S - Another option would be a pass-through query that does `SELECT * FROM TableName` since Recordsets returned by pass-through queries are always "not updatable".

Comment: Informix ODBC does not support SQL_ACCESS_MODE. There is no code within the driver to limit or make a connection read only.

Answer (score 0):

Best safest solution is for the Informix DBA to create a new user for your Access front end with GRANT SELECT permissions only for the tables your application will be querying.